# device mapper on RHEL6 unable to create devs for LVM logical volume

Tags: rhel, lvm, xen, device-mapper

I have XEN guest running RHEL6, and it has a LUN presented from the Dom0.  This contains an LVM volume groups called vg_ALHINT (INT for Integration  and ALH is an abbreviation of its Oracle database name). The data is Oracle 11g. The VG was imported, activated and udev created the maps for each logical volume.

However device mapper did not create mappings for one of the logical volumes [LV], and for the LV in question it created /dev/dm-2 with different major minor number compared to the rest of LVs.

```
#  dmsetup table
vg_ALHINT-arch: 0 4300800 linear 202:16 46139392
vg0-lv6: 0 20971520 linear 202:2 30869504
vg_ALHINT-safeset2: 0 4194304 linear 202:16 35653632
vg0-lv5: 0 2097152 linear 202:2 28772352
vg_ALHINT-safeset1: 0 4186112 linear 202:16 54528000
vg0-lv4: 0 524288 linear 202:2 28248064
vg0-lv3: 0 4194304 linear 202:2 24053760
vg_ALHINT-oradata:     **
vg0-lv2: 0 4194304 linear 202:2 19859456
vg0-lv1: 0 2097152 linear 202:2 17762304
vg0-lv0: 0 17760256 linear 202:2 2048
vg_ALHINT-admin: 0 4194304 linear 202:16 41945088
```

** You can see above vg_ALHINT-oradata is empty.

```
# ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
[root@iui-alhdb01 ~]# ls -l /dev/mapper/
total 0
crw-rw---- 1 root root  10, 58 Apr  3 13:43 control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:43 vg0-lv0 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:43 vg0-lv1 -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 14:35 vg0-lv2 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:43 vg0-lv3 -> ../dm-3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:43 vg0-lv4 -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:43 vg0-lv5 -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:43 vg0-lv6 -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:59 vg_ALHINT-admin -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr  3 13:59 vg_ALHINT-arch -> ../dm-9
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253,  7 Apr  3 14:37 vg_ALHINT-oradata
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Apr  3 13:59 vg_ALHINT-safeset1 -> ../dm-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8 Apr  3 13:59 vg_ALHINT-safeset2 -> ../dm-11
```

vg_ALHINT-oradata was not created until when I ran `dmsetup mknodes`

```
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

 202        0   26214400 xvda
 202        1     262144 xvda1
 202        2   25951232 xvda2
 253        0    8880128 dm-0
 253        1    1048576 dm-1
 253        2    2097152 dm-2
 253        3    2097152 dm-3
 253        4     262144 dm-4
 253        5    1048576 dm-5
 253        6   10485760 dm-6
 202       16   29360128 xvdb
 253        8    2097152 dm-8
 253        9    2150400 dm-9
 253       10    2093056 dm-10
 253       11    2097152 dm-11
```

dm-7 would have been vg_ALHINT-oradata and it's missing.
I ran `dmsetup mknodes` and `dm-7` was created yet still missing from `/proc/paritions`.

```
# ls -l /dev/dm-7
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 253, 7 Apr  3 13:59 /dev/dm-7
```

Its major and minor numbers are `253:7` yet the devices and the same LVs in its VG have 202:nn

`lvs` tells me this LV was suspended:

```
# lvs
    Logging initialised at Thu Apr  3 14:44:19 2014
    Set umask from 0022 to 0077
    Finding all logical volumes
  LV       VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv0      vg0       -wi-ao----   8.47g
  lv1      vg0       -wi-ao----   1.00g
  lv2      vg0       -wi-ao----   2.00g
  lv3      vg0       -wi-ao----   2.00g
  lv4      vg0       -wi-ao---- 256.00m
  lv5      vg0       -wi-ao----   1.00g
  lv6      vg0       -wi-ao----  10.00g
  admin    vg_ALHINT -wi-a-----   2.00g
  arch     vg_ALHINT -wi-a-----   2.05g
  oradata  vg_ALHINT -wi-s-----  39.95g
  safeset1 vg_ALHINT -wi-a-----   2.00g
  safeset2 vg_ALHINT -wi-a-----   2.00g
    Wiping internal VG cache
```

The disc was created from a snapshot from our production databases. Oracle was shutdown and VG had been exported prior to the snapshot. I should note I perform this same take for 100s of databases weekly via a script.
Because this was a snapshot then I have the table from device mapper from the original and I used this to try and recreate its missing table:

```
0 35651584 linear 202:16 2048
35651584 4087808 linear 202:16 50440192
39739392 2097152 linear 202:16 39847936
41836544 41943040 linear 202:16 58714112
```

After suspending the device with `dmsetup suspend /dev/dm-7` I ran `dmsetup load /dev/dm-7 $table.txt`

Next I tried to resume this device,

```
# dmsetup resume /dev/dm-7
device-mapper: resume ioctl on vg_ALHINT-oradata failed: Invalid argument
Command failed
#
```

Any ideas because I'm really lost. (Yep I've rebooted and re-snapshotted this lots and always have the same problem. I've even reinstalled this server and run `yum update`.)

// EDIT.

I forgot to add that this is the original dmsetup table from our production environment and I tried to load the oradata layout into our integration server like I noted above.

```
#  dmsetup table
vg_ALHPRD-safeset2: 0 4194304 linear 202:32 35653632
vg_ALHPRD-safeset1: 0 4186112 linear 202:32 54528000
vg_ALHPRD-oradata: 0 35651584 linear 202:32 2048
vg_ALHPRD-oradata: 35651584 4087808 linear 202:32 50440192
vg_ALHPRD-oradata: 39739392 2097152 linear 202:32 39847936
vg_ALHPRD-oradata: 41836544 41943040 linear 202:32 58714112
vg_ALHPRD-admin: 0 4194304 linear 202:32 41945088
```

//EDIT

I ran vgscan --mknodes and had:

```
The link /dev/vg_ALHINT/oradata should have been created by udev but it was not found. Falling back to direct link creation.



# ls -l /dev/vg_ALHINT/oradata
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Apr 3 14:50 /dev/vg_ALHINT/oradata -> /dev/mapper/vg_ALHINT-oradata
```

Still cannot activate this and had this error message:

```
device-mapper: resume ioctl on failed: Invalid argument Unable to resume vg_ALHINT-oradata (253:7)
```

//EDIT

I see stack traces in /var/log/messages:

```
Apr  3 13:58:09 iui-alhdb01 kernel: blkfront: xvdb: barriers disabled
Apr  3 13:58:09 iui-alhdb01 kernel: xvdb: unknown partition table
Apr  3 13:59:35 iui-alhdb01 kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:7: xvdb too small for target: start=58714112, len=41943040, dev_size=58720256
Apr  3 14:02:31 iui-alhdb01 ntpd[1093]: 0.0.0.0 c612 02 freq_set kernel 5.242 PPM
Apr  3 14:02:31 iui-alhdb01 ntpd[1093]: 0.0.0.0 c615 05 clock_sync
Apr  3 14:30:13 iui-alhdb01 kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:2: xvdb too small for target: start=58714112, len=41943040, dev_size=58720256
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: INFO: task vi:1394 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel:      Not tainted 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: vi            D 0000000000000000     0  1394   1271 0x00000084
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff88007aef19b8 0000000000000082 ffff88007aef1978 ffffffffa000443c
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff88007d208d80 ffff880037cabc08 ffff880037cda0c8 ffff8800022168a8
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff880037da45f8 ffff88007aef1fd8 000000000000fbc8 ffff880037da45f8
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: Call Trace:
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa000443c>] ? dm_table_unplug_all+0x5c/0x100 [dm_mod]
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff810a7091>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xb1/0xf0
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf1f0>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x50
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff815286c3>] io_schedule+0x73/0xc0
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf230>] sync_buffer+0x40/0x50
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8152918f>] __wait_on_bit+0x5f/0x90
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf1f0>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x50
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81529238>] out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x78/0x90
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8109b310>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x50
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf1e6>] __wait_on_buffer+0x26/0x30
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa0085875>] __ext4_get_inode_loc+0x1e5/0x3b0 [ext4]
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa0088006>] ext4_iget+0x86/0x7d0 [ext4]
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa008ec35>] ext4_lookup+0xa5/0x140 [ext4]
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81198b05>] do_lookup+0x1a5/0x230
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81198e90>] __link_path_walk+0x200/0xff0
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8114a667>] ? handle_pte_fault+0xf7/0xb00
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811a3c6a>] ? dput+0x9a/0x150
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81199f3a>] path_walk+0x6a/0xe0
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119a14b>] filename_lookup+0x6b/0xc0
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119b277>] user_path_at+0x57/0xa0
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8104a98c>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1ec/0x480
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119707b>] ? putname+0x2b/0x40
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8118eac0>] vfs_fstatat+0x50/0xa0
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c4645>] ? nr_blockdev_pages+0x15/0x70
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8115c4ad>] ? si_swapinfo+0x1d/0x90
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8118ec3b>] vfs_stat+0x1b/0x20
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8118ec64>] sys_newstat+0x24/0x50
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff810e2057>] ? audit_syscall_entry+0x1d7/0x200
Apr  3 14:33:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8100b072>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: INFO: task vi:1394 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel:      Not tainted 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: vi            D 0000000000000000     0  1394   1271 0x00000084
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff88007aef19b8 0000000000000082 ffff88007aef1978 ffffffffa000443c
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff88007d208d80 ffff880037cabc08 ffff880037cda0c8 ffff8800022168a8
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff880037da45f8 ffff88007aef1fd8 000000000000fbc8 ffff880037da45f8
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: Call Trace:
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa000443c>] ? dm_table_unplug_all+0x5c/0x100 [dm_mod]
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff810a7091>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xb1/0xf0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf1f0>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x50
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff815286c3>] io_schedule+0x73/0xc0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf230>] sync_buffer+0x40/0x50
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8152918f>] __wait_on_bit+0x5f/0x90
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf1f0>] ? sync_buffer+0x0/0x50
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81529238>] out_of_line_wait_on_bit+0x78/0x90
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8109b310>] ? wake_bit_function+0x0/0x50
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811bf1e6>] __wait_on_buffer+0x26/0x30
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa0085875>] __ext4_get_inode_loc+0x1e5/0x3b0 [ext4]
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa0088006>] ext4_iget+0x86/0x7d0 [ext4]
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa008ec35>] ext4_lookup+0xa5/0x140 [ext4]
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81198b05>] do_lookup+0x1a5/0x230
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81198e90>] __link_path_walk+0x200/0xff0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8114a667>] ? handle_pte_fault+0xf7/0xb00
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811a3c6a>] ? dput+0x9a/0x150
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81199f3a>] path_walk+0x6a/0xe0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119a14b>] filename_lookup+0x6b/0xc0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119b277>] user_path_at+0x57/0xa0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8104a98c>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1ec/0x480
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119707b>] ? putname+0x2b/0x40
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8118eac0>] vfs_fstatat+0x50/0xa0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c4645>] ? nr_blockdev_pages+0x15/0x70
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8115c4ad>] ? si_swapinfo+0x1d/0x90
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8118ec3b>] vfs_stat+0x1b/0x20
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8118ec64>] sys_newstat+0x24/0x50
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff810e2057>] ? audit_syscall_entry+0x1d7/0x200
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8100b072>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: INFO: task vgdisplay:1437 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel:      Not tainted 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 #1
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: vgdisplay     D 0000000000000000     0  1437   1423 0x00000080
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff88007da35a18 0000000000000086 ffff88007da359d8 ffffffffa000443c
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: 000000000007fff0 0000000000010000 ffff88007da359d8 ffff88007d24d380
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: ffff880037c8c5f8 ffff88007da35fd8 000000000000fbc8 ffff880037c8c5f8
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: Call Trace:
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffffa000443c>] ? dm_table_unplug_all+0x5c/0x100 [dm_mod]
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff810a7091>] ? ktime_get_ts+0xb1/0xf0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff815286c3>] io_schedule+0x73/0xc0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c8a9d>] __blockdev_direct_IO_newtrunc+0xb7d/0x1270
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c4400>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c9207>] __blockdev_direct_IO+0x77/0xe0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c4400>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c5487>] blkdev_direct_IO+0x57/0x60
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c4400>] ? blkdev_get_block+0x0/0x20
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811217bb>] generic_file_aio_read+0x6bb/0x700
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c5fd0>] ? blkdev_get+0x10/0x20
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c5fe0>] ? blkdev_open+0x0/0xc0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8118617f>] ? __dentry_open+0x23f/0x360
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c4841>] blkdev_aio_read+0x51/0x80
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81188e8a>] do_sync_read+0xfa/0x140
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff810ec3f6>] ? rcu_process_dyntick+0xd6/0x120
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8109b290>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811c479c>] ? block_ioctl+0x3c/0x40
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119dc12>] ? vfs_ioctl+0x22/0xa0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8119ddb4>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x580
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81226496>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x20
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff81189775>] vfs_read+0xb5/0x1a0
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff811898b1>] sys_read+0x51/0x90
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff810e1e4e>] ? __audit_syscall_exit+0x25e/0x290
Apr  3 14:35:34 iui-alhdb01 kernel: [<ffffffff8100b072>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Apr  3 14:39:19 iui-alhdb01 kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:7: xvdb too small for target: start=58714112, len=41943040, dev_size=58720256
Apr  3 14:53:57 iui-alhdb01 kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:7: xvdb too small for target: start=58714112, len=41943040, dev_size=58720256
Apr  3 15:02:42 iui-alhdb01 yum[1544]: Installed: sos-2.2-47.el6.noarch
Apr  3 15:52:29 iui-alhdb01 kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:7: xvdb too small for target: start=58714112, len=41943040, dev_size=58720256
Apr  3 15:59:08 iui-alhdb01 kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:7: xvdb too small for target: start=58714112, len=41943040, dev_size=58720256
```

Comment: Please delete all these comments and edit the question instead. Add the information there.

Comment: @Hauke Laging ok done like you requested.

Comment: Your Dom0 is wich os?

Comment: Did you blacklist that lun in the lvm.conf of the Dom0?

Comment: Dom0 is Oracle Unbreakable Linux, and this was based on RHEL5. We have circa 30 guests running on this server with identical disc setups.

Comment: No LUN were black listed because the guest can see LUN, import the VG and mount all LVs except one.

Answer (score 3):

See `devices.txt` in the kernel documentation: Major 202 is "Xen Virtual Block Device", major 253 is LVM / device mapper.

All your `dm-x` devices are `253:n`; they just **point** to `202:n`.

The error message is clear:

```
device-mapper: table: 253:7: xvdb too small for target: start=58714112, len=41943040, dev_size=58720256
```

It seems there has been a change to the XEN device. Your `vg_ALHPRD-oradata` cannot be loaded because it tries to access storage space on `202:16` which simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Hauke, thank-you.  If the devices size was changed, then loading the original table back in via dmsetup should make this work, and doing this didn't.  Glad you pointed out the 202/252 numbers.

Comment: @si_l No, it should not, of course. The problem is (probably) not the DM device configuration but the **underlying** device (`xvdb`).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like multipath on the Hypervisor refuses to update its maps for LUN sizes.

This LUN was originally 28Gb and was later grown to 48Gb on the storage array.

The VG information thinks its 48G and indeed this disc is 48G, but multipath won't update and thinks it's still 28G.

Multipath clinging to 28G:

```
# multipath -l 350002acf962421ba
350002acf962421ba dm-17 3PARdata,VV
size=28G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
  |- 8:0:0:22   sdt   65:48    active undef running
  |- 10:0:0:22  sdbh  67:176   active undef running
  |- 7:0:0:22   sddq  71:128   active undef running
  |- 9:0:0:22   sdfb  129:208  active undef running
  |- 8:0:1:22   sdmz  70:432   active undef running
  |- 7:0:1:22   sdoj  128:496  active undef running
  |- 10:0:1:22  sdop  129:336  active undef running
  |- 9:0:1:22   sdqm  132:352  active undef running
  |- 7:0:2:22   sdxh  71:624   active undef running
  |- 8:0:2:22   sdzy  131:704  active undef running
  |- 10:0:2:22  sdaab 131:752  active undef running
  |- 9:0:2:22   sdaed 66:912   active undef running
  |- 7:0:3:22   sdakm 132:992  active undef running
  |- 10:0:3:22  sdall 134:880  active undef running
  |- 8:0:3:22   sdamx 8:1232   active undef running
  `- 9:0:3:22   sdaqa 69:1248  active undef running
```

Real disc size on storage:

```
# showvv ALHIDB_SNP_001
                                                                          -Rsvd(MB)-- -(MB)-
  Id Name           Prov Type  CopyOf            BsId Rd -Detailed_State- Adm Snp Usr  VSize
4098 ALHIDB_SNP_001 snp  vcopy ALHIDB_SNP_001.ro 5650 RW normal            --  --  --  49152
```

Just to be sure I have the right disc:

```
# showvlun -showcols VVName,VV_WWN| grep -i  0002acf962421ba
ALHIDB_SNP_001          50002ACF962421BA
```

And the VG thinks its 48G

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_ALHINT
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  30
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             exported/resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                5
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               48.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12287
  Alloc PE / Size       12287 / 48.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               qqZ9Vi-5Ob1-R6zb-YeWa-jDfg-9wc7-E2wsem
```

When I rescan the HBAs for new discs and reconfigure multipthing, the disc still displays 28G, so I tried this an dhad no change:

```
# multipathd -k'resize map 350002acf962421ba'
```

Versions:

```
lvm2-2.02.56-8.100.3.el5
device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-46.100.5.el5
```

**Workaround**
Because I could not think of solutions I did this:
I did not write earlier that I run OVM 3.2 on top of, so part of my solution will include OVM.
i) Shutdown guests on Xen via OVM.
ii) Remove discs
iii) Delete LUNs from OVM 
iv) Unpresent LUNs from hypervisors.
v) OVM rescan storage.
vi) Wait for 30 mins ;)
vii) Present my discs to the Hypervisors with different LUN IDs.
viii) OVM rescan storage

And now fantastically I see 48G discs.

```
# multipath -l 350002acf962421ba
350002acf962421ba dm-18 3PARdata,VV
size=48G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
  |- 9:0:0:127  sdt   65:48    active undef running
  |- 9:0:1:127  sdbh  67:176   active undef running
  |- 9:0:2:127  sddo  71:96    active undef running
  |- 9:0:3:127  sdfb  129:208  active undef running
  |- 10:0:3:127 sdmz  70:432   active undef running
  |- 10:0:0:127 sdoh  128:464  active undef running
  |- 10:0:1:127 sdop  129:336  active undef running
  |- 10:0:2:127 sdqm  132:352  active undef running
  |- 7:0:1:127  sdzu  131:640  active undef running
  |- 7:0:0:127  sdxh  71:624   active undef running
  |- 7:0:3:127  sdaed 66:912   active undef running
  |- 7:0:2:127  sdaab 131:752  active undef running
  |- 8:0:0:127  sdakm 132:992  active undef running
  |- 8:0:1:127  sdall 134:880  active undef running
  |- 8:0:2:127  sdamx 8:1232   active undef running
  `- 8:0:3:127  sdaqa 69:1248  active undef running
```